# swift UIColor extension of "cannot assign to value: 'self' is immutable"

Tags: swift, struct, extension-methods, nsobject

I wrote an extension of `UIColor` to change alpha directly:

```
public extension UIColor {

    public var rgbaComponents: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        var components: [CGFloat] {
            let c = cgColor.components!
            if c.count == 4 {
                return c
            }
            return [c[0], c[0], c[0], c[1]]
        }
        let r = components[0]
        let g = components[1]
        let b = components[2]
        let a = components[3]
        return (red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }

    public var alpha: CGFloat {
        get {
            return cgColor.alpha
        }
        set {
            var rgba = rgbaComponents
            self = UIColor(red: rgba.red  // error here: "cannot assign to value: 'self' is immutable"
            , green: rgba.green, blue: rgba.blue, alpha: newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

but there is an error:

> cannot assign to value: 'self' is immutable

But extension of Date to assign to self is OK

```
public extension Date {

    public var day: Int {
        get {
            return Calendar.current.component(.day, from: self)
        }
        set {
            let allowedRange = Calendar.current.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: self)!
            guard allowedRange.contains(newValue) else { return }

            let currentDay = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: self)
            let daysToAdd = newValue - currentDay
            if let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: daysToAdd, to: self) {
                self = date // This is OK
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it because of `UIColor` is from `NSObject` and Date is a Swift struct? What is the root cause?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct it is because Date is a struct (value type) and UIColor is a class (reference type).

When you assign to self for a struct you are really just updating all the properties of that structure (simply put) so the actual memory location doesn't change.  So you are not actually mutating the value of self itself.

However when you assign to self for a class you are creating an entire new class in memory so when you assign it to self you are trying to mutate self.  Even if it was allowed how would anything holding a reference to the colour handle it as they would still be holding a reference to the original class.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is a solution using an extension.  You can't change the alpha of a `UIColor` without creating a new one and you can't change self as it is immutable.